# Is there something wrong with the usage of Sqlite in Monotouch in this piece of code? Getting malloc() errors

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin.ios

See the piece of code below that is using Sqlite in Monotouch. It represents one of many methods and all kind of look the same.
Is everything cleaned up as it should be? In the Sqlite docs I read that I should **finalize** every prepared statement but I cannot find a matching call. So, am I missing something?

As far as I can see, I'm opening closing and disposing everything correctly.
Nevertheless I'm getting **malloc() errors** from Sqlite randomly. This has started recently so it could also be a problem in the Sqlite version of MT itself as my code has not been changed.

```
using ( SqliteConnection oConn = this.CreateDBMSConnection() )
{
  oConn.Open ();

  using ( SqliteCommand oCmd = new SqliteCommand (
    "SELECT CollaborationItems.*, CollaborationParticipants.intStatus AS intParticipantStatus   FROM CollaborationItems " +
"LEFT JOIN CollaborationParticipants ON CollaborationItems.intItemID = CollaborationParticipants.intItemID " +
"WHERE CollaborationItems.intID = @intD", oConn ) )
  {
    oCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue( "@intID", iItemID );

    using ( SqliteDataReader oReader = oCmd.ExecuteReader (  ) )
    {
      while ( oReader.Read( ) )
      {
         // [...] - some code omitted.

         // The next call again create a DMBS connection, has similar using etc.
         oItem.Participants = this.GetEventParticipants(oItem);
      }
      oReader.Close( );
    }
  }
  oConn.Close( );
}
```

This is the exception I receive:

> Mono.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException: malloc() failed out of memory  at
>   Mono.Data.Sqlite.SQLite3.Prepare (Mono.Data.Sqlite.SqliteConnection
>   cnn, System.String strSql, Mono.Data.Sqlite.SqliteStatement previous,
>   UInt32 timeoutMS, System.String& strRemain) [0x0022a] in
>   /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/Mono.Data.Sqlite/Mono.Data.Sqlite_2.0/SQLite3.cs:343
>   at Mono.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand.BuildNextCommand () [0x00019] in
>   /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/Mono.Data.Sqlite/Mono.Data.Sqlite_2.0/SQLiteCommand.cs:230

Comment: Approximately how many rows are returned from this query?  What does `GetEventParticipants` do? (You can remove your calls to close, if you have using statements, btw)

Comment: There are no queries that return an extraordinary large number of rows. Let's say 100 rows is the maximum. But like I said: this is unchanged from previous version and it ran fine on iPad 1 with 512MB of RAM and now I'm getting the exceptions even on iPad 3 with 1GB.
GetParticipants() is a call to another query that looks pretty much the same as the one I've posted (meaning: same semantics)

Comment: So you are running a second query inside a while loop?  I think you need to reorganize your code, this is an N+1 inefficiency: http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/join/nested-loops-join-n1-problem  Look into using a join, or using 2 queries instead.

Comment: I know. This is not about inefficiency. I'm hunting a malloc() error.

Comment: Right, the `malloc` error could definitely be caused by the inefficiency though.  An N+1 is going to use a crazy amount of memory compared to the properly written SQL.

Comment: I am also suddenly getting malloc errors on a PC with 8gb of memory. I am executing 15,000 select statements in a row which only return 1 row each. A previous version of SQLite or EF worked fine, just can't narrow down which one was the culprit.

Answer (score 1):

The location of an **out of memory** condition means that's where you ran out of memory - but it does **not** means it is where all the memory was allocated.

IOW there's likely nothing wrong **where** `malloc` fails - beside not having the available memory it request. You *might* be looking at the wrong place to find your (previous) memory usage.

Also since `sqlite` is unmanaged code a low memory condition will not trigger the GC (unless iOS sends a warning to the application). So a *high* memory usage bump, in this code, is more likely to cause this *failure* that many other places in your application. This can make you suspect the wrong part of the code.

To find (or at least ensure) you're looking at the right place I suggest you to use Apple's Instruments and monitor the application total memory usage. That will tell where (and when) most of the memory is allocated.

That might still point to `sqlite` but, even then, you should be able to get a far more precise picture of the issue.

Comment: Looking at Instrument's activity monitor: which column is the one I should look at? Real Mem or Virtual Mem?